# should I worry about concurrent access to a dict in a multithreaded python script?

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, concurrency

I would like to speed up the execution of a script by launching several threads of independent, asynchronous operations which were otherwise launched one after the other.

I used [the example from concurrent.future docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) and adapted it to my code:

```
import concurrent.futures

def myfunc(elem):
    elem['ascii'] = ord(elem['name'])

mylist = [
    {'name': 'a'},
    {'name': 'b'},
    {'name': 'c'},
    {'name': 'd'},
    {'name': 'e'}
    ]

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(myfunc, elem): elem for elem in mylist}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        try:
            future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('error: '.format(exc))

print mylist
```

The code works as expected but should I worry about the concurrent access to `mylist` or whether is is correctly locked and accessed in a serial way (or whatever is correct so that data is consistent)?

In the real program the dictionary will be much larger and I would like to launch ~500 workers.

Comment: list and dictionaries are not used from multiple threads in your example: list is accessed only by the main thread and each thread works with its own dictionary.

Comment: yes, each thread will work on its own dictionary from the list `mylist`. What I was worried about is that when a dictionary is modified, the list is indirectly updated as well, possibly by several threads simultaneously (except if it is implemented as some kind of a list of pointers to the dicts, in which case it would not change)

Comment: why mutating an object that happens to be an item in a list should affect the list in any way? For example, you could use a tuple (an immutable object) instead of the list and it won't break your example

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: I do not know, this is why I was asking the question. I can imagine an implementation where the list and its contents is one big chunk in memory (as opposed to a list of pointers (in C semantics)) and any change in one of the components changes the whole list, which could create issues in concurrent access. It is good to know that Python is as great in the inside as it is on the outside :)

Comment: this behaviour does not depend on the implementation. Everything is an object in Python (whether it is CPython, Pypy, IronPython, Jython) so "reference" semantics is expected. There are containers that may store their items as plain C types in "one big chunk in memory" -- `bytearray`, `array.array`, `numpy` arrays and create corresponding Python objects on access. It still doesn't change the semantics because corresponding Python objects are immutable (int, float, bytes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to speed up the execution of a script by launching several threads

Because of the [challenges posed by CPython's implementation](http://www.dabeaz.com/GIL/), you should probably use the [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) instead if you're interested in performance.  Note that this will require a design that's a bit more sophisticated with respect to how the workers communicate and/or interact with data structures that should be shared.

Now, on to your question:

> should I worry about the concurrent access to mylist or whether is is correctly locked and accessed in a serial way (or whatever is correct so that data is consistent)

The `list` will behave correctly in a **multithreaded** environment, but if you have any semantic layered on top that needs atomicity, you will need your own locking.  Say, for example, your design requires/expects that the `list` should always have seven elements and some workers will do a `pop()` followed by an `append()`.  You will need your own locks to protect the workers against concurrent access in between those.

Comment: My current (serial) implementation is not optimal because each call to the function implies a network timeout. Launching _n_ threads could speed up _n_ times the execution (the threads will be "waiting together" for the timeout). This is to say that the gain will not come from the script itself but rather on paralellizing the network timeouts. As for your second point: the list length will not change,   the only modifications are on some dictionary keys (very much in the spirit of the example)

Comment: it is fine to use threads for IO-bound tasks and even for CPU-bound tasks (if GIL is released by a C extension such as numpy, regex, lxml)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I think multithreaded I/O bound work is still slow for multicore targets, but it's possible that newer releases have addressed this.  [See also](http://bugs.python.org/issue7946).